# Firebase realtime DB events not triggered in APK, but are in editor

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have built a Unity game which needs to listen for updates to a database object. When I run the game in the Unity editor - realtime DB changed events are triggered and the game reacts accordingly. When I publish to my Android device, however, these events dont seem to get registered.

When I check the Unity logs, the error I see is:

*InitializationException:  Firebase modules failed to initialize: invites (missing dependency), messaging (missing dependency), remote_config (missing dependency)*

Though I clearly have those packages imported.

Any thoughts?

```
firebaseReference.GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted) {
            // Handle the error...
            print ("failed watchers");
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            // Do something with snapshot...
            print ("set watchers");
        }
    });

    firebaseReference.ChildChanged += HandleChildChanged;
```

Comment: I have the same error with the messaging (the only one I'm using), but it happens only when I run in a Samsung device; on 2 Motorola, 2 LG and Editor the problem doesn't happen. I suspect it is something related to Google Play services (or kind of).

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to Google Services; you have two solutions (I'll post only the related to the messaging, that's the only one I used):
 1) Check the dependencies, using the Firebase plugin, and show a message to the user (the plugin does it for you).
 2) Try to register the Firebase messaging service, catch any errors and fail silently (if that's the case);

Here is the code for solution 1:
**PushNotificationManager.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase;

public class PushNotificationManager : MonoBehaviour {
    DependencyStatus dependencyStatus = DependencyStatus.UnavailableOther;

    public void Start()
    {
        dependencyStatus = FirebaseApp.CheckDependencies();
        if (dependencyStatus != DependencyStatus.Available)
        {
            FirebaseApp.FixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                dependencyStatus = FirebaseApp.CheckDependencies();
                if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available)
                {
                    InitializeFirebase();
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogError("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: " + dependencyStatus);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            InitializeFirebase();
        }    
    }


    protected void InitializeFirebase()
    {
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenReceived;
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
    }
    public void OnTokenReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.TokenReceivedEventArgs token)
    {
        Debug.Log(token.Token);
    }

    public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Received a new message from: " + e.Message.From + " / " + e.Message.Data.ToString());
    }
}
```

And here is the code for solution 2:
 **PushNotificationManager.cs**

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System;

    public class PushNotificationManager : MonoBehaviour {
        public void Start()
        {
            InitializeFirebase();
        }


        protected void InitializeFirebase()
        {
           try
           {
              Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenReceived;
              Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               Debug.LogError("Erro no Firebase: "+e);


           }
        }
 //   (...)
}
```

**NOTE**:
As far as I know, there's no solution till now, so this is only to prevent crashes to your app.
More info here: [Bugs reported [Firebase-Unity]](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/rqWZ2frS_VY)